# AngularJS Select | After selecting an id from a JSON show the rest of the information of that id

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, model-view-controller

I have a JSON saved that has plenty information:

[image: JSON RESPONSE]

I am able to fill a select menu with all the names of each element inside the JSON this way:

```
<select ng-model="car.marca" ng-options="item.brakeId as item.name for item in fillBreaks" class="form-control cforms" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Sleccionar Marca</option>
 </select>
```

Getting this as result: a select menu filled with the names:

[image: Select dropdown filled]

I am able to get the BreakId of the selected element, in this case is saved in 'car.marca' using ng-model.

```
ng-model="car.marca"
```

My question is, Based on the selected element lets say 'BrakeId: 9' how can I display the rest of the information of that selected id?

I want to display the price, description, stock, and so on.

Comment: Where are you trying to display the information? Outside the select in another section or within the select area?

Comment: May I ask why was my answer not good? It's a much simpler solution and in-line with AngularJS guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected object by doing a `find` on `fillBreaks` (should be `fillBrakes`?) for an object with a matching `brakeId` using `ng-change` like below. This will allow you to display the additional brake information while keeping `car.marca` true to holding just a `brakeID`.

```js
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
exampleApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.car = null;
  $scope.fillBreaks = [
    { brakeId: 0, name: 'Brake A', description: 'Good brakes', price: 100, stock: 1 },
    { brakeId: 1, name: 'Brake B', description: 'Great brakes', price: 200, stock: 1 },
    { brakeId: 2, name: 'Brake C', description: 'The best brakes', price: 300, stock: 1 }
  ];
  $scope.brakeInfo = null;
  $scope.getBrakeInfo = function(brakeId) {
    $scope.brakeInfo = $scope.fillBreaks.find(function(item){return item.brakeId == brakeId});
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="car.marca" ng-options="item.brakeId as item.name for item in fillBreaks" ng-change="getBrakeInfo(car.marca)" class="form-control cforms" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Sleccionar Marca</option>
  </select>
  <p>{{ brakeInfo }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your ng-options to grab the entire selected object, instead of just it's ID.

`ng-options="item as item.name for item in ctrl.fillBreaks"`

[See this JSFiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/gaky6hxt/)

P.S. A little trick to remove the Placeholder option from the dropdown is to add `style="display: none;"` to it, so that it can't be intentionally selected; also illustrated in the JSfiddle